# MVC input action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have problem with input of Action method.

I have this code:

```
public ViewResult List(int page_number = 1) {

    ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel {

        Products = repository.Products
        .OrderBy(m => m.ProductID).Skip((page_number - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize),
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo {

            CurrentPage = page_number,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()


        }
    };

    return View(model);

}
```

and I have this route configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: null,
         url: "Page{page}",
         defaults: new { Controller = "Product", action = "List" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I type URL: `http://localhost/Page2` or `http://localhost/Page3`
the value of `page_number` is always `1`.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Template parameter in URL template needs to match parameter name in Action.

So either change configuration to match action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: null,
     url: "Page{page_number}",
     defaults: new { Controller = "Product", action = "List" }
);
```

Or change action to match configuration

```
public ViewResult List(int page = 1) { ... }
```